# How to export Flows in PostMan?

Tags: postman

I have created few Flows in PostMan. It is needed for other team for usage.

If any available option for export it would be helpful for other.

Is there any option?

Thanks

Comment: Flows is still a `Beta` feature that is rapidly changing all the time. That feature isn't available at the moment. If you're creating them in a Team Workspace, members of that team will have access to the Flows already. You can also add a feature request here for the functionality https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-flows/discussions